# Merge is creating new record for children

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

#### Merge is creating not working for children @OneToMany

I am using Php Doctrine and I am using `@OnToMany` mapping with `cascade` `all`. I have a parent class `SalesOrder` and child class `SalesOrderDetails`.

1. `Case 1 : Save` - When I save new record sales order along with sales order details. It is working as expected.
2. `Case 2 : Update` - Here is the issue, I am merging the `Sales Order` which is fine however its inserting new records for its children `SalesOrderDetail` instead of updating it. Ideally it should it apply `merge`but for children as well but its not.

As of now, I am getting the Sales Order Details by id from DB then change the properties of it.  Ideally that should not be the case, mean if we set the id to unmanned object, it should update instead of creating new records.

**Note:** 
1. Merge is working with parent object if it has the id value.
2. I am not adding new item here, I am just updating the existing recorded through merge.

**SalesOrder.php**

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="sales_orders")
 * */
class SalesOrder extends BaseEntity {
       /**
       * @OneToMany(targetEntity="SalesOrderDetail",cascade="all", mappedBy="salesOrder" )
       */
       protected $itemSet;

           function __construct() {
                $this->itemSet = new ArrayCollection();
          }
}
```

**SalesOrderDetail.php**

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="sales_order_details")
 * */
class SalesOrderDetail extends BaseEntity {

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue * */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="SalesOrder")
     * @JoinColumn(name="order_no", referencedColumnName="order_no")
     */
    protected $salesOrder;

}
```

[image]

## Debug Mode screen

[image]

#### If I use `cascade={"merge"}`

I am getting different error if I am using Cascades `merge`

> Type: Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException Message: Multiple
>   non-persisted new entities were found through the given association
>   graph: * A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrder#itemSet' that was not configured
>   to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrderDetail@0000000052218380000000007058b4a6.
>   To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrderDetail#__toString()' to get a
>   clue. * A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrder#itemSet' that was not configured
>   to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrderDetail@0000000052218071000000007058b4a6.
>   To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\SalesOrderDetail#__toString()' to get a
>   clue.

Comment: Do you really need that merge? It sounds weird for updating entities when flush will be enough (unless you're merging Sales into EM before applying any changes)

Comment: The entire data I get from the front-end and create the entities out of it so its not managed object which can be saved on flush automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your mapping, [`cascade` needs an array](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/d21305378ce5a49a6a1a79e058c16179f66dcbc8/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L1539)

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="SalesOrderDetail", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="salesOrder" )
 */
 protected $itemSet;
```

Comment: If I use `array` instead of `ArrayCollection`, I am getting the error `Class '' does not exist`. Detailed error is added in answer. To avoid this error I used `ArrayCollection`.

Comment: I meant that `cascade` needs an array, so you should have this `cascade={"all"}` instead of `cascade="all"` in your `@OneToMany` mapping